# Surface of genus $0$

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Is it true that any closed and compact surface with genus $0$ is homeomorphic to a sphere?

If so, how might one go about proving this? Or can someone point me in the direction of some textbook that discusses this problem?

Comment: How are you defining genus?

Comment: So that the Euler characteristic $\chi(S) = 2 - 2g$.

Comment: What you want is the classification theorem for surfaces. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces.